# Add Javascript to a Single Custom Admin Configuration Page in Magento 2.4 with XML

Tags: layout, javascript, magento2.4, xml, system-config

I am developing a custom module and need to load a javascript function on my "Custom" admin configuration page created with system.xml at url "admin/system_config/edit/section/<my_section>". I have dynamic fields with dropdowns that need to cross reference each selection. When using `<div data-mage-init="">`, the initially loaded rows work, but when new rows are added, they don't load the data-mage-init javascript as they are initialised at page load.

I want to access the function via:

```
<div id="custom-id" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click here!</div>
```

The code needs to be packaged into the module at "app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule", and not into a theme.

How do I add a head  tag via XML to my "my_section" page only to include a js file, so it doesn't load on every other admin page?